# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot up after a sudden shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, desktop-background

I am running ubuntu alongside windows 10 and I wanted to have a cool live wallpaper so I found an app on GitHub called Komorebi https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi.

I followed the instructions of the app step by step and then when I clicked on change wallpaper my screen turned into green pixels for a second and the computer shutdown suddenly after that I can't boot again into ubuntu.

It is not a hardware issue as I can boot into windows very easily. For illustration the app makes you move files to /System/Resources/thenameofthewallpaperyouchose
 In addition, I can't access my ubuntu files through windows with the ext2reader program

Comment: Was it a clean shutdown (ie. file systems closed cleanly, all buffers synced via SysRq keys, command etc) or an unclean shutdown (power button etc)?  If it was an unclean shutdown I'd boot a 'live' system and check your file-systems (ie. `fsck`) before I tried booting it.

Comment: it was unclean shutdown as if someone removed the power cable, I tried fsck and gave me an error and I tried fixing packages with dpkg and it downloaded some packages and removed some and the problem remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost 100% guarantee that your Windows driver **ext2reader** corrupted your Ubuntu installation. Uninstall it asap. Boot to a Ubuntu Live and see what's left of your Ubuntu installation. Backup important files asap.

Try this to see if it'll fix Ubuntu for you...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If you did a packaged install of Komorebi, I'd recommend removing it...

```
sudo apt purge komorebi
```

If you did a manual (advanced) installation of Komorebi, you should remove these PPAs, as they may comprise your system with updates for gnome that are not compatible.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging -y
```

Comment: I installed ext2reader on windows after the problem in order to backup my important files
so it is not the problem.

Comment: but I entered recovery mode and opened terminal then I mounted the drive and I entered: **sudo apt remove komorebi** and this fortunately solved the problem.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: But I am wondering why ext2reader could cause a problem?

Comment: @HusseinKassem All Windows drivers that pro-port to be able to r/w to ext2/3/4 partitions end up corrupting them.

Comment: Thanks for your help